# Taking a list of IDs from a table, add multi select form fields for each ID, and post the results of the form including the IDs to another table

Tags: php, html

Currently I am constructing a form where I'd like to include the following work list by date functionality:

- User selects a date
- All IDs and Names of active users are drawn from an established MySQL table, presented in rows
- 2 new fields for each ID/User are presented with multiple selections
- The ID and the 2 new multiple selection fields are passed to another table with columns ID, date, and 2 columns (AM Work and PM Work) to add the results of the multiple selection fields.

I understand that one field holding results of the multiple selection fields will be held and that there will be multiple date and ID rows to store these values, that is not a problem for me.

I've created the form table with the ID and name retrieved from the established table, and included the two fields where my multiple selections are the same in both, retrieved from another table of work types.

I first tried multiple foreach loops to pass the ID and then each AM work type selected, and then each PM work type selected. I can do this for one record, however I'd like to be able to take multiple IDs and parse multiple AM and PM multi-select work types.

```
    //This is part of a loop that covers the AM work entry that I've tried already:

    // IF THE VALIDATION PASSES - SEND THE INFORMATION TO THE DB
    if ($valid) {

        // SET NEW VALUES FOR THE EXISTING RECORD
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


        //INSERT THE WORK DATA INTO THE DATABASE
        $capture_id = "";
        foreach($_POST["id"] as $key => $capture_id){

            //REARRANGE DATE FOR INSERT
            $work_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($work_date));

            //CAPTURE EACH VALUE FROM THE ARRAYS AS VARIABLES
            $id = $_POST["id"][$key];

            // FOR EACH PIECE OF AM WORK ADD TO WORK HISTORY TABLE
            $capture_am_work = "";
            foreach($_POST["$am_work"] as $key => $capture_am_work){ 

                $am_work = $_POST["am_work"][$key];                         

                //INSERT THE AM DATA INTO work_history_table
                $sql = "INSERT INTO work_history_table (date, id, am_activity_id)
                values(?,?,?,?)";
                $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $q->execute(array($work_date, $id, $am_work, $pm_work));

            }
        }
    }
```

Form details are:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="work_scheduling.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>id</th>
               <th>name</th>
               <th>AM Work</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php 
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE status = 'Active'";

            $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $sth->bindParam(':query',$query,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->execute();
            foreach ($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><input name="id[]" type="text"  placeholder="id" value="';
                    echo $row['id'];
                    echo '" readonly></td>';
                    echo '<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><input name="name[]" type="text"  placeholder="id" value="';
                    echo $row['name'];
                    echo '" readonly></td>';
                    echo '<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">';
                    echo '<select name="am_work[]" class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Click To Select AM Work" multiple tabindex="10">';
                    echo '<option value=""></option>';
                    $am_work_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, diary_task_name FROM diary_task_category WHERE status='Active'");
                    while ($am_work_rows = $am_work_query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                        $am_work_value = $am_work_rows['id'];
                        echo '<option value="';
                        echo $am_work_value;
                        echo '">';
                        echo $am_work_rows['id'],": ",$am_work_rows['diary_task_name'];
                        echo '</option>';
                     }
                     echo '</select>';
                     echo '</td>';
                 echo '</tr>';
                }
            Database::disconnect();
            }
        ?>

    </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Update</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

******* ANSWER - CODE USED SUCCESSFULLY *******

```
    //table setup

    foreach ($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
        $id2 = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];

        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td><input name="id2[]" type="number"  placeholder="id2" value="';
            echo $id2;
            echo '"></td>';

            echo '<td><input name="name[]" type="text"  placeholder="name" value="';
            echo $name;
            echo '"></td>';

            echo '<td>';
            echo '<select name="id2[';
            echo $id2;
            echo '][am_work][]" class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Click To Select AM Work" multiple tabindex="10">';
            echo '<option value=""></option>';
            $am_work_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, diary_task_name FROM diary_task_category WHERE status='Active'");
            while ($am_work_rows = $am_work_query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                $am_work_value = $am_work_rows['id'];
                echo '<option value="';
                echo $am_work_value;
                echo '">';
                echo $am_work_rows['id'],": ",$am_work_rows['diary_task_name'];
                echo '</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
    }



    //loop

    foreach($_POST["id2"] as $record_id => $value){
        $val1 = $record_id;

        foreach($value["am_work"] as $key => $am_work_value){
            $val2 = $value["am_work"][$key];

           //INSERT THE AM DATA INTO work_history_table
           $sql = "INSERT INTO work_history_table (date, horse_id, am_activity_id)
           values(?,?,?)";
           $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
           $q->execute(array($work_date, $val1, $val2));
        }

    }
```

ultimately the expected results would be entries into a table that iterates through each ID, and then for each id, iterate through each multi-selected items.

Please be gentle - I'm completely new to all of this!

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We expect you to ask an actual, _specific_ question here - and right now, it is rather hard to find such in your post.

Comment: `foreach($_POST["$am_work"]` – the dollar sign in the key is a mistake here, I assume? Or is that an essential part of your problem / error already? (If it is a mistake, PHP would likely have been able to alert you to that on its own already - if you had proper PHP error reporting enabled. If you don’t, please go do that first of all now.)

Comment: "ultimately the expected results would be entries into a table that iterates through each ID, and then for each id, iterate through each multi-selected items."  This is ultimately the question - how can I take the IDs and the new fields associated with them and pass them to the database? Re the $ sign in am_work - I have removed this and the information posts '0' values for ID and am_work.

Comment: Can you show us your form that you are sending this data from? It probably makes the most sense that you make modifications there - changing field names in a way that you automatically get your data in form of arrays you can easily loop over on the PHP side.

Comment: Added the form details, this is embedded in a table.

Comment: Where does the code fail?

Comment: You’re using the `foo[]` syntax here already for your form field names to create arrays, but I would change the format a bit though - use the record ID as key on the first level, and whatever the current field value _means_ as second: `name="data[5][name]"`, `name="data[5][am_work][]"` (still an extra set of `[]` at the end here, because you want to be able to select multiple options in that field), etc. Then you can loop over `$_POST['data']` afterwards - use the extended foreach syntax, to get the record ID as key, and the sub-array as value.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm going to try this later when I get a spare moment - currently the code fails because it cycles through all the am_work and adds a row for all the IDs in the table and then moves onto the next one. I wondered whether my array syntax may have been incorrect.

Comment: @misorude I've declared the am_work field as `name="id2[ ][am_work][ ]"`

Comment: @misorude ive also looped through with the following:
`foreach($_POST["id2"] as $key => $id2){
foreach($id2["am_work"] as $key2 => $am_work_value){
$sql = "INSERT INTO work_history_table (date, horse_id, am_activity_id)
 values(?,?,?)";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($work_date, $id2, $am_work_value));}}`
- the AM work values enter the database but the id's do not - any advice?

Comment: With `name="id2[ ][am_work][ ]"` the actual ID is missing (if you want to follow the way I outlined) - put it into the first set of braces, `name="id2[789][am_work][]"` - 789 would be the id of the record you want to edit here. Then when you loop over this with the foreach loop you had shown, `$key` would hold this value.

Comment: @misorude Thankyou for your help on this, I appreciate it. Should I use the id I've extracted from the table to populate the value of the field as the key value? or should I just iterate a count and place this value within the braces in the row iteration after the select statement to populate it when constructing the table? or does it matter as long as there is an array of key values? in terms of extracting the keys as entries into the reference id field in the new table, is it as simple as `foreach($_POST["id2"] as $key){ foreach($id3["am_work"] as $key2 => $am_work_value){ insert etc.etc.`?

Comment: You need the record id of the records you want to update, so I think it makes sense to use that as index to begin with. If you just used a loop counter, you would still need to put the record ID into an extra field. You need to use the extended foreach syntax then to get access to both key and value (value here been an array itself) - `foreach($foo as $key => $value)` Of course, since you know the key _is_ your record ID here, you might use a variable name that better communicates that to begin with `foreach($_POST["id2"] as $record_id => $value)` or sth.

Comment: @misorude you've been brilliant - Thankyou! I have an answer to my query and you've been most patient :0) Essentially I left the ID2 value as `[]` and added the value of the id from the database into am_work thus: 
        echo '<select name="id2[';
        echo $id2;
        echo '][am_work][]" .......
with this I looped through in the code I've updated above, to work through the values and add them to the database.